# How can i view a new activity using FAB button in Android Studio

Tags: android

does anyone has the solution to this problem. i'm trying to create a note keeper application. i'm trying to replace the fab button to view a new note. i have tried using :

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), NoteActivity.class));

        }
    });
```

i also tried this:

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(NoteListActivity.this, NoteActivity.class));
```

the app keeps closing when i click on the button.

Comment: please add logcat in your question

Comment: this method you are using seems fine. please post your error log.

Comment: Also, show the code of your new activity specially onCreate!

Comment: It could be the Manifest declaration. Just a guess with that little info though

Comment: Actually, I'm new at this and I don't know how to extract the logcat....is there any other way to make the question more clear?